# r calculate frequencies for all factor levels by subgroup for several columns

Tags: r, function, apply

I need to count frequencies of all levels of variable by group for several columns in R.  I have a data frame of several columns, including a grouping variable. The other columns have 3 levels - 0, 1, and NA.

This is what I have:

```
#     a     b     c     d   group
1     1     1     1     NA    1
2     1     0     1     0     1
3     0     0     NA    1     1
4     0     NA    1     0     2
5     1     1     0     0     2
6     1     0     0     1     2
7     NA    0     1     NA    2
```

This is what I need:

```
group   level   a   b   c   d
1   0   1   2   0   1
    1   2   1   2   1
    NA  0   0   1   1
2   0   1   2   2   2
    1   2   1   2   1
    NA  1   1   0   1
```

I used dplyr and lapply to solve this.

I tried

```
df %>%
  mutate(a = factor(a, levels=0:1)) %>%
  group_by(group, a) %>%
  summarise(freq=n()) %>%
  complete(a, fill=list(freq=0))
```

This gets me what I want, but I would have to do it by each column.

I also tried

```
lapply(df[(2:70)],  table)
```

That gets me the frequencies, but not by group.

I basically somehow need to combine the two pieces of code. I need to be able to combine the two pieces of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, level, -group) %>%
 group_by(group, var, level) %>%
 summarise(val = n()) %>%
 spread(var, val, fill = 0)

  group level     a     b     c     d
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     1     2     0     1
2     1     1     2     1     2     1
3     1    NA     0     0     1     1
4     2     0     1     2     2     2
5     2     1     2     1     2     1
6     2    NA     1     1     0     1
```